# Receive data in the MainActivity from BroadcastReceiver everytime it is called

Tags: java, android

I have developed an android app that uses `BroadcastReceiver` class to detect Wi-Fi Network changes. In this receiver I get the `ssid` of the network. Now I want that this ssid obtained by the receiver should be passed to the MainActivity everytime the receiver is called so that some ssid comparison can be done in the MainActivity.
How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override `onReceive()` Method

```
final NetworkChangeReceiver networkChangeReceiver = new NetworkChangeReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                super.onReceive(context, intent);
                         // put your code here to check wi-fi and to get ssid value
            }
        };
        final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
        wifibox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    registerReceiver(networkChangeReceiver, filter);
                } else {
                    unregisterReceiver(networkChangeReceiver);
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Glad to know it is works for you. You should upvote the answer for make it more effective